# How to inject a service in AutoMapper Profile class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am working on a project where we have AutoMapper Profile class which has all the mappings. However, for some reason, I need to call some service and in order to call that service, I need to call inject that service in `Profile` class.

SO my class looks like following:

```
public class MyClass : Profile
{

public MyClass
{
   //somemapping here
}

}
```

Now, say I want to inject a service, it needs to take that service in the constructor and the constructor would look like following:

```
public MyClass(IService service)
    {
       //somemapping here
    }
```

Now, currently

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

calls all the classes which inherit from profile class `auto magically`, and it does not call the parameter constructor.

Now my question is what is the best way to call a service in Automapper profile class?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2208).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddAutoMapper()` extension method is just synthatic sugar.
For your needs you can always initialize Automapper manually:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
   cfg.AddProfile(new MyClass());
});
```

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Maybe that solve your issues.

Comment: But with that approach there's not dependecy injection inside Profile Classes, and what about if you have a lot of Profiles in diferent places, you don't need to do a Mapper.Initialize() everywhere, its what AutoMapper Dependecy Injection try to solve.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to use DI while building profile class? Youp, just pass your class using your dependency container: `cfg.AddProfile(new MyClass(provider.GetService<IService>()))`

Answer (score 5):

You can’t inject dependencies into `Profile` classes, but you can do it in `IMappingAction` implementations.

First add `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` package to your project. Then create an `IMappingAction` class like this:

```
public class SetSomeAction : IMappingAction<SomeModel, SomeOtherModel>
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public SetSomeAction(IService _service)
    {
        service = _service;
    }

    public void Process(SomeModel source, SomeOtherModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //here you use the service and change destination
    }
}
```

Then in profile class:

```
public class SomeProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SomeModel, SomeOtherModel>()
            .AfterMap<SetSomeAction>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm thick here but where is the DI of `IService` happening? Looks like some kind of setter to me

Comment: @MartinWickman In the Startup.cs as usual you can register your service. ex: `services.AddScoped<IYourServiceInterface, YourServiceImplementation>();`   in the `SetSomeAction` class inject it in ctor.

Comment: please visit this url: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html